# Appending a subprocess to a list seems to just append the subprocess object location in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

Using the following command at the console prints the local MAC address of wlan0's NIC. I want to integrate this into a script where the 0th sublist of a list will be filled with the local MAC in exer

```
ifconfig wlan0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

The list in use, localisation, gets it's 1st and 2nd sublists from  a dict called scanned.

So I want to have the local MAC in the 0th sublist and an entry for every entry in the 1st and 2nd sublists. I have tried the code:

```
for s in scanned:
    localisation[0].append(subprocess.Popen("ifconfig wlan0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'", shell=True))
```

but I just get

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x2bf0f50>
```

For every entry into the list. Although there are the correct amount of entries.

I also have the problem that for some reason the program prints the output of the code to the screen which I don't want to happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for replacing pure shell scripting in python, you might want to look at the [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/) module -- `sh.grep(sh.ifconfig('wlan0'), '-o', '-E', r'([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')`

Comment: you should use python regex instead of grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my try:

use `check_output` gives the output of that command.

```
In [3]: import subprocess

In [4]: subprocess.check_output("ip link show wlan0 | grep link | awk '{print $2}'",shell=True).strip()
Out[4]: '48:5d:60:80:e5:5f'
```

use `ip link show` instead of ifconfig save you a sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

the popen object is a file object in a sense.

```
from subprocess import *
handle = Popen(c, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
handle.stdin.write('echo "Heeey there"')
print handle.stdout.read()
handle.flush()
```

The reason why not ALL output is redirected for you is stderr=PIPE, it must be otherwise that will be echoed into the console no matter what. Redirecting it to PIPE is a good idea.

Also, using `shell=True` is generally a bad idea unless you know why you need it.. in this case (i don't think) you don't need it.

Aaaand finally, you need to devide your command that you would like to execute into a list, at least a 2 item list or more. example:

```
c = ['ssh', '-t', 'user@host', "service --status-all"]
```

which would be `ssh -t user@root "service --status-all"` normally, notice the NOT splitted part of `"service --status-all"` because that's a parameter sent as a whole to the SSH client in my example.

Without trying, try:

```
c = ["ifconfig", "wlan0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'"]
```

---

Or even:

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling just `Popen` only returns a new `Popen` instance:

```
In [54]: from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

In [55]: from shlex import split   #use shlex.split() to split the string into correct args

In [57]: ifconf=Popen(split("ifconfig wlan0"),stdout=PIPE)

In [59]: grep=Popen(split("grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'"),
                                                   stdin=ifconf.stdout,stdout=PIPE)

In [60]: grep.communicate()[0]
Out[60]: '00:29:5e:3b:cc:8a\n'
```

use `communicate()` to read the data from the `stdin`,`stderr` of a particular `Popen` instance:

```
In [64]: grep.communicate?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<bound method Popen.communicate of <subprocess.Popen object at 0x8c693ac>>
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py
Definition: grep.communicate(self, input=None)
Docstring:
Interact with process: Send data to stdin.  Read data from
stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.  Wait for
process to terminate.  The optional input argument should be a
string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data
should be sent to the child.

communicate() returns a tuple (stdout, stderr).
```